# An example for $f\in H^1(\Omega)$ but not in $L^\infty(\Omega)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I am looking for canonical examples of functions $f\in H^1(\Omega)$ which are not in $L^\infty(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: What is $\Omega$?

Answer (score 0):

For example when $\Omega$ is $B(0,1)$ you can look for $x \mapsto |x|^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \le 0$. If the dimension is $N=3$ then one finds that $\alpha =1$ works *i.e* that $f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{|x|}$ is unbounded but that $f \in H^1 (B(0,1))$.

Comment: In two dimensions, you can use something like $\ln(1/|x|)^\alpha$.